# HP fanfic: Harry is sent to Azkaban, dies and returns to being a child after a deal with Death. Death also sent Harry's brother back

Tags: story-identification, harry-potter, fan-fiction

Harry has a brother who everyone thinks is the real child of prophecy. Stuff happens and Harry is sent to Azkaban where I think he dies. He makes a deal with Death, who sends him back in time. Death also mentions that he had sent Harry's brother back once before, so his brother was already a returnee. I think Death also makes harry an heir to Slytherin. Harry is secretly lord Slytherin and attends Hogwarts at the same time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That sounds very much like [Dodging Prison and Stealing Witches](https://www.fanfiction.net/s/11574569/Dodging-Prison-and-Stealing-Witches-Revenge-is-Best-Served-Raw) by LeadVonE.

> Harry Potter has been banged up for ten years in the hellhole brig of Azkaban for a crime he didn't commit, and his traitorous brother, the not-really-boy-who-lived, has royally messed things up. After meeting Fate and Death, Harry is given a second chance to travel to the past, squash Voldemort, dodge a thousand years in prison, and snatch everything his hated brother holds dear.

> He'd been in here for just over ten years now. This year marked the point when his stay in this prison would overtake his stay in the last one, those miserable excuses for human beings that called themselves the Dursleys.
> It made no sense. Why had his parents dumped him there? The official reason was that he'd been mistaken for a squib, but that didn't explain why they refused to speak to him after he came to Hogwarts.
> His brother, John Potter, was believed by all to be The-Boy-Who-Lived, but Harry knew that wasn't true. He also knew the Headmaster knew it wasn't true.
> For some reason, the headmaster really didn't like him. When the chamber of secrets had been opened in his second year, and a girl killed, Dumbledore had convinced the world that he was the culprit.

> Death jumped back in. "We're going to send your soul back in time to several years before you leave for Hogwarts. We want you to make sure Riddle dies, and we want you to make sure the prophecy is fulfilled."

> Fate's eyes shone. "And this is exactly the reason why you're going to be our champion this time, Harry, and not John. You think things through. We already let John re-do the timeline once and he still failed."

> "There are three possible lordships you are close enough to being able to claim for my influence to work. Peverell, Gryffindor, and Slytherin."
> Fate started pacing again.
> "The Peverell and Gryffindor lines are closely linked to you through blood, and it would take only a slight modification of your blood to allow you to claim them. The Slytherin line could be yours through old family magics called the right of conquest, whereby the conqueror of the last of a line can lay claim to that line's family magics, provided they didn't initiate the conflict that led to the death of the line. This includes titles since they're based on family magics."